# User-defined language not applying to specified file types in Notepad++

Tags: syntax-highlighting, notepad++, highlighting

I have created a fairly simple user-defined language in Notepad++, and given it an associated extension. But, when I open files I have named with that extension, nothing happens. No syntax highlighting, or comment highlighting.

Any idea what I have done wrong?

The settings for the extension do not have a leading `"."`, as specified in the Notepad++ docs.

Answer (score 9):

This has been fixed, so I guess the whole question could be closed or deleted. I'm not sure in which version they fixed it, but in the latest v6.5.1 everything works as intended.

1. Go to menu `Language > Define your language...`
2. Create a new language or select from the dropdown menu an existing one
3. In the `Ext.` text box add your desired extension with no leading "." and space separated if you have multiple extensions.
4. Now open a file with such extension and it is properly highlighted. To confirm that the User Defined Language extension is correct, you can also take a look at the `userDefineLang.xml` usually stored in your `%APPDATA%\Notepad++\` folder.

Answer (score -3):

Here is a clear guide for how to create your own Notepad++ syntax definition for a new language.

- http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2006/11/25/creating-a-user-defined-language-in-notepad.aspx

Comment: The page you linked does not have any information pertaining to his question.

Comment: This guide is far from clear. It shows which menus to click but not much about what the various fields mean.