# Notepad++ - shortcut for choosing user defined language

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting, shortcut

In notepad++ I have defined a new user language, called blob_base.

When I am opening some TXT files, I want to choose this language (for syntax highlighting and for text folding and other things).

I always go to the tab language-> and choose blob_base, and it is quite frustrating to do this each time.

Is there a way to create a key shortcut for choosing user defined language?

Thanks,

Kobi

Comment: possible duplicate of [User defined language in Notepad++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057578/user-defined-language-in-notepad)

Answer (score -1):

Goto Define your language > Select your language , then type "txt" without dot "." for Extension.
If there are multiple extension, type them with space like this "txt log dat".